# Why does this function work if called internally?

Tags: c++

If I call this function stringToUpper(str2) in the currencyConverter.cpp itself, its works and return upper case.

```
void currencyConverter::stringToUpper(string &s)
{
   for(unsigned int l = 0; l < s.length(); l++)
  {
    s[l] = toupper(s[l]);
  }
}
```

However I have a file named `unitTest.cpp`, and it does this:

```
#include "unitTest.h"
#include "currencyConverter.h"

CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_REGISTRATION(unitTest);


unitTest::unitTest() {
}

unitTest::~unitTest() {
}

void unitTest::setUp() {
}

void unitTest::tearDown() {
}

void stringToUpper(string&);
void unitTest::testStringLowerToUpper()
{
string str = "ILOVECPLUSPLUS";
string str2 = "ilovecplusplus";

cout << "\nChecking if string 1 '" << str << "' equals string 2 '" << str2 << "'";
CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(str,str2);

//this part i will use my stringToUpperFunction to test.
currencyConverter c;
c.stringToUpper(str2);

cout << str2 << endl;
}
```

When I try to print `str2`, it remains as `ilovecplusplus` instead of being capitalized.

Whats wrong with my code or call?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057523/string-reference-not-updating-in-function-call-in-c

Comment: I don't understand, it doesnt work for me thou , my str2 still lower case

Comment: Have you double check that the unit test suite is linking in the newest version of the library which contains currencyConvertor?

Comment: What is some loose declaration `void stringToUpper(string&)` doing in your unit test code? What is the purpose of it? In any case, the code you posted will "work". If something doesn't work for you, it means that you are doing something differently.

Comment: And why are you checking you strings for equality *before* actually calling `stringToUpper`?

Comment: After some experience you'll write `string str2 = "ihatecplusplus";`